# An alternative design to insert/update of talend

Tags: talend

I have a requirement in Talend where in I have to update/insert rows from the source table to the destination table. The source and destination tables are identical. The source gets refreshed by a business process and need to update/insert these results in the destination table.

I had designed for the 'insert or update' in tmap and tmysqloutput. However, the job turns out to be super slow

As an alternative to the above solution I am trying to do design the insert and update separately.In order to do this, I was wanting to hash the source rows as the number of rows would be usually less.

So, my question I will hash the input rows but when I join them with the destination rows in tmap should I hash the destination rows as well? Or should I use the destination rows as it is and then join them?

Any  suggestions on the job design here?

[image: hash design]

[image: tmap configuration]

Thanks
Rathi

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the same database, you should not use ETL loading techniques but ELT loading so that all processing will happen in the database. Talend offers a few ELT components which are a bit different to use but very helpful for this case. I've had things to speed up by multiple magnitudes using only those components.

It is still a good idea to use an indexed hashed field both in the source and the target, which is done in a same way in loading Satellites in the Data Vault 2.0 model.

Alternatively, if you have direct access to the source table database, you could consider adding triggers for C(R)UD scenarios. Doing this, every action on the source database could be reflected in your database immediately. Remember though that you might need to think about a buffer table ("staging") where you could store your changes so that you are able to ingest fast, process later. In this table only the changed rows and the change type (create, update, delete) would be present for you to process. This decouples loading and processing which can be helpful if there will be a problem with loading or processing later on.

Comment: Hi tobi6, thanks for the reply. I cannot use triggers or any new objects on my source as its data is loaded based on CDC in SQL Server, any new objects would cause issues in syncing between sql server and mysql. Also, with ELT components the source and destination tables must be on the same schema, and in my case they aren't. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Hey, CDC is a very good thing to work with in this case. I'd only create an additional staging table in my schema and just put all information from CDC there. Then you'd have all data in one schema and can use ELT loading. Although, thinking about it, isn't the CDC data providing all information you need already? So you could create one branch to insert, and a second branch to update? Only keep in mind that you should be able to restart the process if it fails.

Comment: The CDC loads not one schema but several schemas. My source is a join of all those tables. And the joins give me a denormalized version of all the tables put together, which inturn is further consumed by reports. Hence, I cannot use the CDC in this case

Comment: Then I haven't understood your pipeline quite yet. Where is the CDC data stored? Why not copy it? Why join beforehand? I think there could be some sort of possibility of decoupling.

Comment: SQL Server has 3 databases which are CDC'ed to 3 schemas in mysql. I join multiple tables in the 3 schemas and generate a dataset, this is used to insert/update a table in another schema in mysql. This is the pipeline

Comment: I see... still, I'd consume the schemas into MySQL and then join etc. The data has to be in your vicinity to be able to produce better results.

Comment: You mean, I must culminate all the 3 schemas from the source and the one schema from destination into a single single schema?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i believe that you should use hash component for destination table as well.
Because than your processing (lookup) will be very fast as its happening in memory

If not than lookup load may take more time.

Comment: Hi PreetyK, thanks for replying. So, my source table will only have very few records and my destination table is massive, should I load all the destination rows as well in tHash? Would this not cause issues?

Comment: than go without hash component for destination.

Comment: Thanks PreetyK. There are times when thash goes for out of memory and heap space error. How do I handle such scenarios? This large amount of data comes only once a while.